# How to resize disk of virtual machine using Azure.Net SDK/ Fluent API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk-.net, dotnet-sdk, azure-fluent-api

I want to resize my os disk space but getting "Disk resizing is allowed only when creating a VM or when the VM is deallocated."

```
Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.RestClient restClient = GetRestClient(requestObject);
            var computeClient = new ComputeManagementClient(restClient) { SubscriptionId = requestObject.SubscriptionId };
            var ObjVirtualMachines = computeClient.VirtualMachines.GetAsync(requestObject.ResourceGroupName, requestObject.VirtualMachineName, null, new System.Threading.CancellationToken()).Result;
            var disktodetach = ObjVirtualMachines.StorageProfile.OsDisk;
            ObjVirtualMachines.StorageProfile.OsDisk.DiskSizeGB = requestObject.DiskSize;
            var newUpdateVM = computeClient.VirtualMachines.CreateOrUpdateAsync(requestObject.ResourceGroupName, requestObject.VirtualMachineName, ObjVirtualMachines).Result;
            resizeDisk = newUpdateVM.ProvisioningState;
```

Comment: Check this link [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.compute.models.disk.disksizegb?view=azure-dotnet)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [1_bug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1385292/1-bug). Posting your suggestions as answer to help other community members.

you cannot Increase the disk size for a running VM. Rather you can increase the disk size of a VM by shutting down the VM and following the below code.

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName="properties.diskSizeGB")]
public int? DiskSizeGB { get; set; }
```

[image]

Before using the above code check weather your code includes creationData.creationoption field is empty.

for further information check [Disk.DiskSizeGB Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.compute.models.disk.disksizegb?view=azure-dotnet)